# jQuery não funcionando no Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Fiz uma brincadeirinha no Codepen, para compartilhar no Github. Que é um efeito de os elementos aparecerem quando você da *scroll* sobre eles.

Pelo Codepen, estava funcionando perfeitamente tanto no IE quanto em outros navegadores, porém, quando eu passei para página HTML para jogar no GItHub, estava funcionando em todos os navegadores menos no IE. Sinceramente não entendi o que está acontecendo e isso está me deixando perplexo. Estou usando o IE11.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/shEme)

[HTML](https://github.com/FelipeMartinin/fadeonscroll)

Comment: No Stackoverflow é preferível se você conseguir incluir a código relevante na própria pergunta e criar o menor exemplo possível que ainda apresenta o bug. Simplesmente linkar pro seu github significa mais trabalho pra que quiser te ajudar e se existe sempre o risco de o link apodrecer no futuro.

Comment: Olá, como vai? Agradeço a resposta. Sei que é possível colocar um trecho do código no post, porém, como eu não sei qual parte exatamente está com problema, acabei não inserindo. Espero que compreenda a situação.

Comment: É por isso que nós encorajamos você a tentar criar um exemplo de teste que seja pequeno o suficiente para caber na pergunta. De brinde, muitas vezes você descobre o problema sozinho só de tentar fazer isso :)

Comment: Ok. Farei isso daqui pra frente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por acaso ao abrir o index.html no Internet Explorer você verificou se não houve nenhuma política de segurança impedindo a execução dos scripts? normalmente é algo do tipo.

Eu testei o exemplo no Codepen e também baixei o ZIP do seu código no github e está funcionando normalmente no Internet Explorer 11.

A única coisa que percebi "errada" é que existe a versão 1.10.2 do jQuery na pasta js, mas a versão que está sendo usada é a 1.9.1 que está sendo referenciada externamente para os servidores do jquery.com.

Comment: Primeiramente agradeço a resposta. Sinceramente eu não sabia que existia essa possibilidade de bloqueio no IE, mas parece bem plausível sua sugestão. Onde eu poderia ver sobre isso? Tem alguns outros freelas que eu estou trabalhando que está acontecendo exatamente a mesma coisa, e tem me deixado bem perplexo. Mas se for realmente isso me deixa aliviado. E o fato de ter funcionado aí já me alivia um pouco. Em relação a versão do jQuery, eu havia feito um pequeno teste com a versão anterior, e esqueci de arrumar o src. Abraço

Comment: @user3130064: A longo prazo, recomendo que você ache uma forma de rodar seus testes via algum servidor web. Tem um monte de coisas que não funcionam direito acessando arquivos via "file://" mas que funcionam via "http://". (Tem uma infinidade de servidores que vc pode escolhern pra isso. Se vc quiser algo simples só pra testar seu html uma possibilidade é o `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`)

Comment: Como o @missingno mesmo disse, é interessante que você use um servidor HTTP para testar seus scripts, assim você fica o mais perto possível do ambiente de produção. O NetBeans por exemplo, possui esse recurso, inclusive com suporte a depuração. Quanto as mensagens de aviso, normalmente elas ficam na barra de status, no entanto não conheço nenhuma maneira efetiva de mostrar os bloqueios, recomendo olhar a aba segurança nas "Ferramentas -> Opções da Internet".

Comment: Ok. Agradeço a ambos pela resposta.